# Error in installing neuralcoref from github

Tags: python, github, virtualenv

I am getting this error even after trying to install neuralcoref from github. I have installed Microsoft visual C++ distributer (version 14.34), Windows SDK add on(10.1), windows software development toolkit (10.1). I installed Cython also in command prompt using direct python virtual enviornment. Can anybody help in resolving this issue. Thanks

```
Obtaining file:///D:/newsclassification/neuralcoref
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Python3.8\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
          return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
        File "C:\Python3.8\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "D:\newsclassification\test_folder\Scripts\cython.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      Processing neuralcoref.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\newsclassification\neuralcoref\bin\cythonize.py", line 168, in <module>
          run(args.root)
        File "D:\newsclassification\neuralcoref\bin\cythonize.py", line 157, in run
          process(base, filename, db)
        File "D:\newsclassification\neuralcoref\bin\cythonize.py", line 123, in process
          preserve_cwd(base, process_pyx, root + ".pyx", root + ".cpp")
        File "D:\newsclassification\neuralcoref\bin\cythonize.py", line 86, in preserve_cwd
          func(*args)
        File "D:\newsclassification\neuralcoref\bin\cythonize.py", line 62, in process_pyx
          raise Exception("Cython failed")
      Exception: Cython failed
      Cythonizing sources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "d:\newsclassification\test_folder\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "d:\newsclassification\test_folder\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "d:\newsclassification\test_folder\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 132, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Ajay Nandal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tz2v830l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 450, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return self.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Ajay Nandal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tz2v830l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\Ajay Nandal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tz2v830l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Ajay Nandal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tz2v830l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\Ajay Nandal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tz2v830l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 239, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 174, in setup_package
        File "<string>", line 163, in generate_cython
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

(test_folder) D:\newsclassification\neuralcoref>pip install Cython
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in d:\newsclassification\test_folder\lib\site-packages (0.29.34)

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

(test_folder) D:\newsclassification\neuralcoref>
```

I tried to install neuralcoref from source and installed the required things, Microsoft visual C++ distributer, Windows SDK. I looked for solutions to the error I received at stackoverflow from more than a week. This error is entirely different from issues solved available here.

Comment: What was the command you ran to produce this error?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. Install NeuralCoref from source
You can also install NeuralCoref from sources. You will need to install the dependencies first which includes Cython and SpaCy.

Here is the process:

venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
cd neuralcoref
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e . The last step "pip install -e . " is giving the above error